# Is the data of an encrypted Android device more vulnerable if it's running a custom ROM?

Tags: encryption, android

Is an Android device that is

- rooted
- has the bootloader unlocked
- is running some mainstream custom ROM
- has encryption enabled, with a strong password

more vulnerable (As in easier to break into, to have its data decrypted by a criminal or law enforcement) than the same device running stock Android (Also encrypted with a strong password)?

Answer (score 2):

If that custom ROM is using hardware-backed keystore (Trusted Execution Environment (TEE)) for screen lock authentication and [file based encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based) (FBE), there's no known way to decrypt `/data` partition without screen lock code as TEE is tamper-resistant by design.

In FBE, encryption keys are cryptographically bound to screen lock code and TEE. This ensures that just by knowing screen lock code is not enough to decrypt **cloned** data. TEE refuses to use its own key for key derivation to decrypt data encryption keys unless user authentication is successful. Tampering with TEE image will hard-brick the device even if bootloader is unlocked.

A threat actor will require you to forcefully unlock the device atleast once. The problem with unlocked bootloader is that they can patch boot image (**boot.img**, contains kernel) without letting you know of the compromise in order to trick you to unlock it and record your screen lock code.

What you need is custom root of trust which is only supported in Pixel and OnePlus. With custom [AVB](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/avb/+/master/README.md), you can sign your own images for integrity protection and relock the bootloader. This is as secure as running stock android. However, some apps that rely on SafetyNet attestation to verify device integrity will refuse to run because boot state is `SelfSigned`.

Even if you are using custom AVB, you need to check if custom ROM is enforcing encryption. Some custom ROMs disable `forceencrypt` flag in **fstab**, which disables encryption from first boot of the OS. Your data remains in plain text. At this point, just by deleting lock settings files, a thief can remove screen lock authentication.

You should also check if your custom ROM is enforcing SELinux, otherwise [any app can make system calls that otherwise wouldn't have been allowed in SELinux `enforcing`](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/lfye5r/selinux_permissive_romskernels_are_very_bad/gmoi05a/). Having root in your custom ROM is not really a problem any more than an unlocked bootloader.

Android architecture has a [design flaw](https://securephones.io/main.html) which is applicable to stock android also. When a user unlocks screen first time since reboot, unlike iOS, android keeps some of the critical keys in memory even after the user relocks the screen. iOS evicts them 10 seconds after the screen is locked. This opens a security hole because as long as some of the data encryption keys are in memory, they can be extracted by law enforcement and can be used to decrypt some of the data in `/data` partition. This requires carefully exposing SoC without disconnecting battery.

Stock android and custom root of trust might be able to stop thieves from owning the device (or data), but when it comes to law enforcement, it depends on their motivation until Google considers eviction of critical data encryption keys from memory when the screen is locked again.

Comment: "iOS evicts them 10 seconds after the screen is locked" -- I'm not familiar with iOS so I may be completely wrong, but wouldn't this not allow apps to access CE storage when the phone is locked? Also how would bio-metrics work if the CE keys were evicted?    "data encryption keys are in memory, they can be extracted by law enforcement" -- an update to this, in Android 11+, Ephemeral Keys are used to specifically prevent cold boot attacks. This does require hardware support, however.

Comment: iOS has a `ClassKey` which can be optionally used by sensitive apps to encrypt and decrypt keys only if the screen is unlocked. Once it's locked, keys that are bound to ClassKey are evicted. Android 9+ has a similar optional feature called auth bound keys that decrypt keys only when the screen is unlocked. CE keys are never evicted and this is why android 11+ has built-in HAL support for Inline Crypto Engine hardware which will also be mandated soon.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the answers missed a very important detail:

> has the bootloader unlocked

If you are worried about the device being physically compromised, then this is the critical component needed for a [cold boot attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack). That being said, Android 11+ attempts to prevent this type of attack with [Ephemeral Keys](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/hw-wrapped-keys), but this only works if the phone's hardware supports it.

Another point of concern is that the phone is rooted. Rooting the phone dramatically increases the attack surface, by exposing root privileges to applications that don't have anywhere near as much testing and publicity as AOSP.

If either of the mentioned points are successfully exploited, then it doesn't matter that encryption is enabled and you are using a strong password. Cold boot attacks directly take the encryption key from memory and root can just request the KeyStore to decrypt all of the data on the phone.

If you are using a non-rooted custom ROM that is a close derivation of AOSP, then it shouldn't be a problem. However, leaving the boot loader unlocked or rooting the phone *is* a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

EncroChat used something very similar to what you describe, and it was 100% hacked. Every single message sent from these phones in a timespan of three months was sent to the police in clear text.

So whatever you do, if you don’t know you are doing, it will be insecure. That doesn’t mean you can’t make it secure, but it may not be easy.

Answer (score 0):

It just depends on the custom ROM. If it is a high quality ROM that has been extensively scrutinized for possible security flaws then the overall security of the system will be good.

If it is a hack that was just modified enough to fit on the device, then everything can happen, from *it is better that the original system* (but I would not hope that...) to *it contains so many back doors that an attacker can easily enter the system without knowing the password*...